# Problem with isAuthenticated in react router's PrivateRoute

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux, react-router

I've got an `isAuthenticated` flag in my auth reducer, and I'm using it in `PrivateRoute` component, but it looks like it's not working at all. Whenever I go to any protected page, and then refresh that page, I'm being redirected to **/** route. `console.log` that I've put inside there is returning true whenever I go to a protected page. IDK where's this problem is coming from.

`localStorage.authToken` in place of `isAuthenticated` in `PrivateRoute` component is working fine, like this:

```js
{localStorage.authToken } ? (
  <Component {...props} />
```

For persisting, in `componentDidMount` of root `App.js`, I'm just calling the `getCurrentUser` action which returns the current logged in user. So, when I go to a protected page, and refresh it, I expect that `getCurrentUser` call to get fired and return the logged in user, but instead on refresh, it's redirecting.

---

**PrivateRoute**

```
import React from "react"
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
```

auth Reducer

```js
const initialState = {
  isAuthInProgress: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authError: null,
  user: {},
  isIdentifyingToken: false,
  token: localStorage.getItem("authToken") || "",
}

const auth = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AUTH_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        authError: null,
      }

    case "AUTH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: false,
        authError: null,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isIdentifyingToken: false,
        user: action.data.user,
      }

    case "AUTH_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: false,
        authError: action.data.error,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
      }

    case "TOKEN_VERIFICATION_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthInProgress: true,
        authError: null,
        isIdentifyingToken: true,
      }

    case "LOGOUT_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        token: localStorage.removeItem("authToken"),
        user: {},
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default auth
```

App.js

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")

    if (authToken) {
      this.props.dispatch({ type: "TOKEN_VERIFICATION_STARTS" })
      this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isIdentifyingToken } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {isIdentifyingToken ? null : (
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
              <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationForm} />
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/feed" component={Feed} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/post/new" component={NewPostForm} />
              <Route path="/post/edit/:id" component={EditForm} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile/:username"component={UserProfile} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/profile/:username/posts" component={UserFeed} />
              <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isIdentifyingToken: state.auth.isIdentifyingToken,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

**getCurrentUser** action.

```js
export const getCurrentUser = (token) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_STARTS" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/users/me`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token,
        },
      })
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_SUCCESS",
        data: { user: res.data.user },
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "AUTH_ERROR",
        data: { error: "Something went wrong" },
      })
    }
  }
```

**Note**: I'm not using libraries like `redux-persist`, nor I want to.

Comment: Did you tried to change the action function to a synchronous function instead asynchronous? Probably the application isn't waiting to finish the request in `getCurrentUser` function.

Comment: yeah that didn't work.

Comment: Initial reducer state is `isAuthenticated: false`. This is the value mapped to the component when the app first loads. Momentarily later when the token check is processed `isAuthenticated` will become true, but by then the redirect has already occurred. You need a solution to persist your redux state and re-hyrdate it upon page loads/reloads.

Comment: @DrewReese Can't I just do `localStorage.getItem("authToken")` in `PrivateRoute`? And It's working, becuase it is a sync operation.

Comment: That or just pull the one your state is initially loaded with. I think that could work as a stopgap.

Comment: @DrewReese I didn't get it- "pull the one your state is initially loaded with"?

Comment: In the initial state for your reducer, `token: localStorage.getItem("authToken") || ""`, in your private route you should be able to map `state.auth.token`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, what's the difference between the two. We're doing the same thing. right? One is synchronous and the other is asynchronous?

Comment: No, one requires only piping in a different value from state in the `mapStateToProps` function and the other requires adding more duplicate logic to get the token from local storage. I believe it is all synchronous. I just figure you already did the work to get the token why do it again in the component. Apply the DRY principle. Either way will likely work though.